# Setting up require.js for a static website and loading custom code as if it was a library

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, requirejs, modernizr

I am new to stack overflow and I was actually curious about my require.js setup, cause it is the  first time I 'm using it and having seen many different approaches/examples, I am not sure if what I 've done so far is correct. 
So, on my index I have on the "head"

```
<script data-main="js/app" src="js/vendor/require-2.2.0-min.js"></script>
```

and at the end of my 'body' I have the Google Analytics snippet. No other script is loaded directly from index.

On app.js that is inside my $projectroot/js folder I have:

```
requirejs.config({
   "baseUrl": "js/vendor",
   "paths": {
      "app": "..",
      "jquery" : ['//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min','jquery-1.12.4.min'],
      "modernizr" : 'modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min',
      "bootstrap" : ['//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min','bootstrap.min'],
      "plugins": '../plugins'
    },
    "shim": {
       "bootstrap": ["jquery"],
       "plugins": ["bootstrap"]
    }
});

requirejs(["app/main"]);
```

Also, my main.js which is on the same folder with app.js contains:

```
define([
   "jquery",
   "modernizr",
   "bootstrap",
   "plugins"
], function($)
{
$(function()
{
console.log('required plugins loaded...');
});
});
```

Finally, my plugins.js is NOT a library, but some custom js code that I need to be loaded last. Is this ok so far? Any drawbacks with this approach? Would it be ok to add the rest of my custom js code on a similar manner? Thank you very much for your responses!!

Comment: This is not a good question for SO. You are essentially asking for a code review but we do have a [site for this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). Also asking about "any drawbacks" makes the question opinion-based because people have very different ideas of what a "drawback" could be. (For instance I've read different opinions about using CDNs. At the end of the day they are *opinions*. What works best would have to be determined on a case by case basis with profiling.)

Comment: Sorry for that! Seems that since I am new here I cannot really understand where the 'line is drawn' between the two sites, but anyway here it is: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/130058/107098

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, the one thing I would change is by putting the global dependecies in your main.js file:

```
define([
   "jquery",
   "modernizr",
   "bootstrap",
   "plugins"
]
```

into your app.js file like so:

```
requirejs(["app/main","jquery","modernizr","bootstrap","plugins"]);
```

This means that your global dependencies will get shared across all of your modules, instead of just in your main.js file. This means you won't have do include them in every file that you want to use them.

Apart from that, it looks good

Comment: I have since then expanded my example and learned a few things, as I 've also added google maps, Facebook Javascript SDK, MomentJS - MomentJS Timezone, a weather widget etc.. What you said came into my mind once I made an index-alt page (alt for an alternative language) and started wanting to show some localized content there, (i.e. Google Maps, Current Time and Date, Weather and Facebook Widgets in Greek) and is absolutely correct since it eliminates duplicates which are a bad practice and I hate.. Marking this as solved - SE was the wrong place for such a question anyway! Thank you Gerard!

Comment: So far everything seems to be working as it should..! For facebook I used  'Facebook module loader' instead of the async plugin, after reading some posts comparing the two, it seemed like a better solution. Once I finish I will update my post/code about this on codereview, perhaps it could be helpful to someone.